# Como definir o input de um programa no Windows?

Tags: windows

Uma pergunta simples. Nos sistemas *NIX, você pode fazer o seguinte:

```
cat input_do_programa.file
"texto exemplo"
input_do_programa.file > meu_programa.exe
```

Há um equivalente para Windows?

Comment: Que eu saiba a mesma coisa funciona: ```programa.exe < entrada.txt```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O programa a ser executado deve vir primeiro. `<` para redirecionar a stream de entrada padrão (stdin) e `>` para redirecionar a stream de saída (stdout) (`>>` para acrescentar ao final do arquivo). Para redirecionar a saída de erro padrão (stderr) utilize `2>`:

```
programa.exe < entrada.txt > saida.txt 2> erro.txt
```

Não é necessário redirecionar tanto entrada quanto saída, pode ser apenas um dos dois.